# GAM posterior simulation for bird population trend

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

## Background

This is a follow-up on my [last post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625260/random-wiggly-smooths-for-100s-of-factor-levels/625277#625277).

I have a GAM of presence of a bird species from a large dataset. There are over 400 sites in my data, where each site corresponds to a unique observer. Site-level variation is the biggest source of variation in the data. There are 30+ years of data, and 20,000 rows.

**My main inferential objective is to capture the overall trend in presence through time**. The rest of the terms in my GAM are just where I'm trying to soak up the rest of the variation, since the data are notoriously noisy.

Here's my model:

```r
m_occ <- bam(present ~ s(year, site, bs = "fs") +
               te(expertise, llcent) + fye + n.period +
               ti(tmin) + ti(visit) + ti(year, k = 33) +
               ti(tmin, visit) + ti(tmin, year) + ti(visit, year) +
               ti(tmin, visit, year),
             data = df_train,
             family = "binomial",
             gamma = 1.4,
             weights = neg_pos_weights,
             select = T,
             discrete = T,
             control = gam.control(trace = T))
```

Obviously, I could do something here with `predict.gam()`, but it's useful to me that the posterior simulation can produces replicates of the trend so I can work with derived quantities. So, I followed [this blog post (From bottom of the heap)](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/06/16/simultaneous-confidence-intervals-for-derivatives/) to do that.

Compared to that blog post, though, I want to shift the trend up to what the actual overall presence of the species would be, after soaking up all of this other variation. And I want it to represent, more or less, the fluctuations around the average abundance (see potential issue with the `offset` later). So, I think, in order to do that, I need to include the intercept term as well as the year smooth in the posterior simulation. Here is my posterior simulation code:

```r
trend_posterior_simulation <- function(model = m_occ, data = df_train, nsims = 25, res = 100){
  
  # Example data
  rand_dat <- data %>%
    slice_sample(n = 1)
  
  # Prediction data for lpmatrix
  pdat <- map_df(seq(1,33, length = res), function(year_value) {
    rand_dat %>% 
      mutate(year = year_value)
  })
  
  # Posterior simulation
  lp <- predict(model, newdata = pdat, type = "lpmatrix")
  coefs <- coef(model)
  vc <- vcov(model, unconditional = T)
  sim <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = nsims, mu = coefs, Sigma = vc)
  want1 <- c(grep("ti\\(year\\)", colnames(lp)))
  want2 <- c(grep("\\(Intercept\\)", colnames(lp))) # Here is where I add the intercept
  want <- sort(c(want2, want1))
  fits <- model$family$linkinv(lp[, want] %*% t(sim[, want]))
  
  # Pivot longer
  result <- fits %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(year = seq(1989,2021,length = nrow(.))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "draw", values_to = "value")
  
  return(result)
  
}
```

## Question

It's my first time doing this. Generally, am I doing everything correctly in this posterior simulation code?